# For which values of $a$, is ${M_{a}=\left\{(x, y) : y^{2}=x(x-1)(x-a)\right\}}$ a sub manifold?

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

In the book of Lee, introduction to smooth manifolds, in page 123, it is asked that

\begin{array}{c}{\text { For each } a \in \mathbb{R}, \text { let } M_{a} \text { be the subset of } \mathbb{R}^{2} \text { defined by }} \\ {M_{a}=\left\{(x, y) : y^{2}=x(x-1)(x-a)\right\}} \\ {\text { For which values of } a \text { is } M_{a} \text { an embedded submanifold of } \mathbb{R}^{2} ? \text { For which }} \\ {\text { values can } M_{a} \text { be given a topology and smooth structure making it into an }} \\ {\text { immersed sub manifold ? }}\end{array}

---

I proceeded as defining $F(x,y) = x(x-1)(x-a) - y^2$, and observing that 
$$DF(x,y) = (3x^2 +2(1+a)x -a \quad -2y)^T.$$
If we can show that $F(x,y) = 0$ is a regular value for $F$, then we can argue that $M_a$ is an embedded smooth manifold.

$DF$ has to have rank $1$, so if $y\not =0$, then nothing to check. If $y= 0$, then we need $3x^2 +2(1+a)x - a\not = 0$ for all $x$ satisfying $x(x-1)(x-a) = 0$, but the latter equation is satisfied only for $x=0, 1, a$.Therefore, $x=0 $ implies $a\not =0$, $x=1$ implies $a\not = 1$, and $x=a$ implies $a \not = 1, 0$. Hence, for any value of $a$ except $0,1$, $M_a$ is an embedded sub manifold of $R^2$ with codimension $1$.

---

**Question:**

Is my solution correct ? Am I missing something ?

Comment: The derivative of $f$ w.r.t. $x$ is not $3x^2+2(1+a)x-a$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown What about now ?

Comment: The curve has a singularity at $(a,0)$ when $a=1$ or $a=0$. I woul d think those are the only exceptions, but I have seen this when studying elliptic curves. Anyway, implicit function theorem is your friend. $\partial F/\partial y$ vanishes only on the $x$-axis, and the rest should be easy.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen You are right, I apparently made a mistake in my calculations. Now corrected. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown What is wrong  the derivative ?

Comment: @onurcanbektas Do you agree that $F(x,y)=x^3-(1+a)x^2+ax-y^2$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Yes,

Comment: @onurcanbektas Good! Then surely you'll agree that what you've written isn't its derivative.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Do you mean, it is partial derivative wrt $x$, or total derivative  or something. I'm not sure what is wrong mathematically if what you are saying is not just a trick of wording.

Comment: Anyway, it's correct now.